# Nilpotent endomorphism: elementary proof

Tags: linear-algebra, nilpotence

Let $E$ a finite dimensional linear space with $\dim E=n$ and $u\in\mathcal L(E)$. I need to prove that $u$ is nilpotent iff $u$ is trigonalizable with unique eigenvalue $0$. I know that the proof would be easy if we use JCF and the minimal polynomial or Cayley-Hamilton theorem but the problem is that this question is asked before these theorems have been introduced. Is there an elementary proof?

Comment: If you know the cyclic decomposition theorem, that also makes it easy.  (And off the top of my head, the "direct" proofs of the fact I can think of all pretty much look like a special case of the proof of the cyclic decomposition theorem.)

Comment: this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518038

Comment: Oh, wait, the result only requires an upper triangular matrix representation, not necessarily one with 1 only on the +1 off-diagonal.  That makes things significantly easier.  (Just show the kernel is nontrivial, pick a nonzero element $x$ of the kernel, then use induction on the dimension and apply inductive hypothesis to $\bar u \in \mathcal{L}(E / \langle x \rangle)$.)