# Show $φ^n= 0$ for $φ:V→V$ a linear endomorphism such that $\mathrm{tr}(\wedge^qφ) = 0$ and $\dim(V) = n$ a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, exterior-algebra, nilpotence

As it is said in the title I'm working on an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. My goal is to show that a linear endomorphism $\varphi:V \to V$ with $\mathrm{tr}(\wedge^qφ) = 0$ for all $q \geq 1$ is such that $φ^n= 0$.

From what I understand I need to show that $\varphi$ is a nilpotent operator, which I've never done before. I already found some answers on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engel%27s_theorem and on the mathstack page [Endomorphism- Nilpotent matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518038/endomorphism-nilpotent-matrices), but since I am not sure to catch well the meaning of Engel's theorem and I didn't see it in class, I was wondering if there is any other way to prove this statement? Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a direct consequence of Cayley-Hamilton Theorem. See this post [Proving that the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are the traces of the exterior powers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131883/proving-that-the-coefficients-of-the-characteristic-polynomial-are-the-traces-of)

The given condition and the above post shows that the characteristic polynomial of $\varphi$ is $T^n$. Cayley-Hamilton shows $\varphi^n=0$.